# Android maps V2 Driving instructions in textview

Tags: android, json, google-maps, geolocation, driving-directions

Im developing a map app in which gps detects my current location and places a marker.Using spinner I get nearby places based on category.What I need is,When I longclick the marker of spinner,Using intent it should show the step by Step navigation instructions in a new page also it should draw route ie polyline from my location to the touched location.

I used http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-and-place-details-using-google-places-api-and-google-maps-android-api-v2/ code for abvove purpose.

Please Help..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on drawing the navigation on the map:

[Google Maps V2 for Android: Draw Driving Direction on Map](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

For adding the Step by Step navigation I guess you would need to change the parsing method a bit in order to get this info from the JSON file you receive.

Comment: How to parse html instructions alone.plz show some code to do it